# VBA code to move to the next line in Excel

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access database for a small Hotel. On the main form I have Guest Information fields...(Name, Address, Phone#, etc). I also have an Excel file that keeps track of bookings for the Hotel. The following code takes the Guest information from my form in Access and populates the labeled cells in my Excel file.

```
Private Sub Command73_Click()
Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("Y:\123files\Edmond\Hotel Reservation Daily.xls")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True

i = i + 1

objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Me.GuestFirstName & " " & GuestLastName
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Me.PhoneNumber
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Me.cboCheckInDate
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = Me.cboCheckOutDate
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = Me.GuestNo
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = Me.RoomType
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = Me.RoomNumber
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 8).Value = Date
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 9).Value = Me.Employee
End Sub
```

Is there a better way to move to the next row in my Excel file, for a new guests info?

EX. I take my first guests info and it populates row A2 of my Excel file. For my next guest it will populate row A3 of my Excel file and so on....

Also When I close my Form in Access it resets the Excel file so the next time I open my form, to make a new reservation it starts at A2, which ultimately overwrites any reservations that already were on the Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

```
' here is how you find the next blank row in the sheet
Dim row as Integer
row = objXLBook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row) = Me.GuestFirstName & " " & GuestLastName
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & row) = Me.PhoneNumber
'etc…
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Dim row = ....causes an error "Expected: end of statement"

Comment: @Edmond Sorry, take out `Dim`

Comment: @Jay I get a user defined type not defined error message when I put Dim sheet As Worksheet in my declarations. Does it not go there?

Comment: @Edmond You can just go with your original approach instead of using the `sheet` variable. The important part is identifying the next empty row and concatenating that with your column letter.

Comment: @Jay You have to forgive me, I am not well versed in VBA. So now that I'm not usign the sheet variable, how would the setup look? Am I removing Dim sheet?

Comment: @Jay. Before your update I figured thats what you were referring to, and I get the "Variable not Defined" error, for sheet

Comment: @Jay The row = now gives me the "variable not defined" error message

Comment: @Edmond `Dim` it first, as an integer.

Comment: @Jay When I run the above code now, nothing happens. It stopped pasting the info from Access to the Excel file.

Comment: @Edmond I'm sorry; without knowing more of the code that you are using, I'm afraid I can't discern the problem. All I was demonstrating is how to find the next row. You'll need to run the code you posted each time a new guest's info is added.

Comment: @Jay Thank you, for all your imput. Would that be a loop? To run the code each time a new guest is added

Comment: @Edmond Well, if that code is in a `Sub`, there would likely be a button on your form that would execute the `Sub` when clicked. If your form actually accepts info for a bunch of guests before exporting to Excel, then yes, you'd have to add a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you need last row in a given range, but not first totally blank row you can also use this:

```
Dim lastRow as Integer
lastRow = objXLWbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'...
```